# Android layout - images seem to be hidden

Tags: android, layout, css, media-queries

Ok, some background - this is a site which I have been asked to create a quick mobile stylesheet for. The site hasn't been built with this in mind, to be perfectly frank - it's a nightmare. Tables, inline style - the whole cahoona.

The main snag I have hit at present is that on the homepage of the site - there is a panel of 6 images floated to show 2 per row in portrait and 3 in landscape. In iOS this works fine, but in every Android browsers this has been tested in the images seen to disappear - although the links remain if you have a prod about.

Anybody able to spot the issue?

Thanks for any help!

http://www.dmls-ltd.com

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you this tool to find what is the exact problem.

http://www.smartjava.org/content/remote-chrome-debugging-android

It's a little bit hard to answer it with your few information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http:// in all the links to the images.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue without being able to pinpoint exactly what it was. Seems to be a bug in the way in which it was dealing with the % widths I had applied to the td/li/a elements. A quick and dirty fixed pixel width for these and it seems to work fine.

Thanks though for the help!